# Can executing DDL command e.g alter query affects the rows of the table?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

I am trying to execute scenarios when DDL commands affects the number of rows of the table,but executing alter command always return 0 number of rows.

a) Table a has 3 columns b,c,d with 3 records inserted.

b) `ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN b`

Dropping column b shouldn't be affecting the rows already in table.

Comment: DDL does not effect specific rows (thee way insert / update / delete does) - it effect the table object.

Comment: Create is a DDL command and creating table as (select * from some_table) returns the rows effected.

Comment: It's the `select` statement that's returning the results. DDL operations are performed on objects \ segments - meaning - structure, not rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

To speak in simple terms, Except for `TRUNCATE` , And `DROP TABLE` no other `DDL` would affect the data (rows) the table holds..

To speak technically, a `DDL` is supposed to touch the schema objects and not the data. TRUNCATE will reset the `High WaterMark (HWM)`. And marked as blocks have no data. `DROP TABLE` will entirely drop the metadata and the data associated with it.

`CREATE` as `SELECT` is something oracle gives specially apart from standard *SQL*, where a *DDL* (`CREATE`) is executed first using the result set metadata(FROM `SELECT`) and then data is loaded too! If the loadimg fails for any reason, the process would be halted and no object creation happens!

Comment: So to conclude there is no DDL command which will return the rows effected speaking in terms of Oracle other than CREATE as Select.

Comment: yes, also `CREATE` as `SELECT` is for creating a new object only, with existing you cant..

Comment: `create table ... as select ...` is not specific to Oracle. It's part of the SQL standard